# issue installing react icons with npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, terminal, npm-install, react-icons

I'm following a react tutorial on lynda.com. I'm trying to install react icons through npm to my react project. I'm getting some weird warnings in the command line that I don't understand. **Here's the result in the tutorial vs. my result:**

This is the **tutorial's** result the terminal.

[image: Tutorial result in shell]

This is **my** result in the terminal:

```
Last login: Sat Aug 11 11:54:48 on ttys005
dashiell-bark-husss-macbook-pro-2:bulletin-board dashiellbark-huss$ npm install --save react-icons
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/.bin/jest as it wasn't installed by /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/jest
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs as it wasn't installed by /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/uglify-js
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/html-minifier/node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs as it wasn't installed by /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/html-minifier/node_modules/uglify-js
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp as it wasn't installed by /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/.bin/esparse as it wasn't installed by /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/esprima
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/.bin/esvalidate as it wasn't installed by /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/esprima
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/espree/node_modules/.bin/acorn as it wasn't installed by /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/espree/node_modules/acorn
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/.bin/browserslist as it wasn't installed by /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/browserslist
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/.bin/browserslist as it wasn't installed by /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/autoprefixer/node_modules/browserslist
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
+ react-icons@3.0.5
added 1 package and removed 1311 packages in 10.061s
dashiell-bark-husss-macbook-pro-2:bulletin-board dashiellbark-huss$
```

Here's a screen shot which may be easier to view:
[image: my result in shell]

Now, when I try to use icons, I get this error:

```
./src/Note.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-icons/lib/fa/pencil' in '/Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/src'
```

I'm guessing this error is related to what the command line showed me when I tried to install the icons.

I'm very new to react and npm, so I'm looking for some guidance on why this isn't acting as expected and how to fix this?

**Update:**

I'm now getting a different error:

```
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/react/index.js'
```

I ran `npm outdated` in the terminal and found some weird results: it looks like npm thinks react, react-dom, and react-script are missing. Honestly this is a bit over my head and I don't know what it means but that looks wrong.

```
dashiell-bark-husss-macbook-pro-2:bulletin-board dashiellbark-huss$ npm outdated
Package        Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
react          MISSING  16.4.2  16.4.2  bulletin-board
react-dom      MISSING  16.4.2  16.4.2  bulletin-board
react-scripts  MISSING   1.1.4   1.1.4  bulletin-board
```

I went into my package.json file and saw that those all have a caret symbol infront of them:

```
"react": "^16.4.2",
"react-dom": "^16.4.2",
"react-icons": "^3.0.5"
```

Full package.json file contents:

```
{
  "name": "bulletin-board",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-icons": "^3.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

**2nd Update:** **An per user Win's suggestion I ran `npm install`.** This changed some things.

This was the result in the command line:

```
dashiell-bark-husss-macbook-pro-2:bulletin-board dashiellbark-huss$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump

> fsevents@1.2.4 install /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v59-darwin-x64/fse.node" is installed via remote

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js

npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

added 1298 packages and updated 88 packages in 24.848s
```

Now, If I use the syntax `import { FaPencil } from 'react-icons/fa'` to import, my page compiles but with these warnings :

```
./src/Note.js
  Line 2:  'FaPencil' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 3:  'FaTrash' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars:
```

But if I use the syntax `import FaPencil from 'react-icons/lib/fa/pencil'` to import, my page does not compile and I get this error:

```
./src/Note.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-icons/lib/fa/pencil' in '/Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/src'
```

**Update 3**:
After fixing a syntax error, I now get a different error

```
'react-icons/fa' does not contain an export named 'FaPencil'.
```

npm version 5.6.0

Comment: Have you tried writing `import { FaPencil } from 'react-icons/fa';` instead?

Comment: Somehow I'm getting a different error _with or without_ the import statement you suggested. My error is now `./node_modules/react/index.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/dashiellbark-huss/Downloads/Ex_Files_Learning_Reactjs/Exercise Files/Ch03/03_02/start/bulletin-board/node_modules/react/index.js'`

Comment: I added some more info in the original post

Comment: Can we see your entire webpack.config.js

Comment: I don't think I have that file in this project, does that make any sense? It doesn't look like the example exercise files from the tutorial have them either.

Comment: @Dashiell can you paste your project files mainly your application file? Might be because you're using Create React App? Paste your entire package.json file

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss actually it looks like you've not installed your initial install of node modules, can you run npm install and tell us the result?

Comment: @Win thanks, I updated my post with more info on what happened after running npm install

Comment: I ended up finding a webpack.config.js file, should I share that?

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss Thanks! you were missing a base installation, I've added the answer you're looking for below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access a paid icon. You will have to use the free pencil icon:

`import { FaPencilAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';`

and then use it like so

`<FaPencilAlt/>`

You can find a list of icons you can use here: https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=Pencil

Anything marked as PRO will not be available.

Comment: I can't believe this is the solution! I wonder why my lynda tutorial didn't think to address that the viewers probably don't have access to paid icons. thank you so much!

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss Glad it's sorted!

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss  Strange.  I'm viewing the same tutorial.  The FaTrash icon works as she describes but the pencil fails unless I used the suggestion above.  Wouldn't there be a FaTrashAlt as well?

Answer (score -1):

I found it quite difficult to install react-icons as well, a fix for me was to simply uninstall and install node.js again. This worked fine for me.